# CSS/Javascript Very Large Image Absolute Positioning Slowdown

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, positioning

I am seeing some strange behavior in Chrome for some image "zoom/pan" code that I'm writing.  I only see the issue in Chrome, because it appears that the other browsers do not render a high quality resized .jpg image.

I am using javascript and absolute positioning (top/left) to move and image around a screen as I click and drag on it.  In my full project, I have a container div that is some percentage of the screen, and then another div containing a large img (4200x4200px). In chrome, the response was very "sluggish" depending on how "zoomed in" to the image I was.  I wrote some simplified tests to show you guys what I'm talking about.

Please run the examples in 1920x1080 resolution or higher in fullscreen mode.  Here is some panning code where my div container is smaller than my image idv (resized to 800x800px).
[Test 1](http://jsfiddle.net/WtjT5/28/light/)
Notice that if the image fills up the height of the div, then panning performance is very bad.  If the shown portion of the image does not take up the full height of the div, it is fairly smooth.

Next here is the same code with the only change being that the div container is set to 1 pixel more than the img div (801px).  Now, the image panning is always very smooth.
[Test 2](http://jsfiddle.net/WtjT5/30/light/)

I have more tests, but stack overflow is limiting me to two links.  Here is the pan handler 
    function boardPanHandler2(event) {
        var newLeft;
        var newTop;

```
    if (gBoardMouseDownFlag) {

            newLeft = gBoardPanLeftStart + event.pageX - gBoardPanPageXStart;


            newTop = gBoardPanTopStart + event.pageY - gBoardPanPageYStart;


            $(".div-board").css('left', newLeft).css('top', newTop);
            //$(".div-board").css('transform', 'translate(' + newLeft + 'px, ' + newTop + 'px)');
    }

    $("h1").text($(".div-board").width() + "," + $(".div-board").height() + " " + gBoardContainerX + "," + gBoardContainerY);
}
```

I am pretty new to html/css/javascript in general, so go easy on me.  Any insight would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to your `.img-board` and any other large image you need to drag around.

```
.img-board
{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WtjT5/34/

Re "The resized image quality in chrome stops looking quite as good"

Undo that first suggestion I made, add a new css class

```
.noantialias{
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

and add and remove that on drag and release. I've updated your fiddle to do this using this when we know the event

```
$(event.target).addClass('noantialias');
```

and since mouseup (release) is bound to window just remove all when that's triggered

```
$('.noantialias').removeClass('noantialias');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WtjT5/41/

Comment: Fantastic!  This does in fact work, although I am curious why.  It appears to make chrome work more like IE and Firefox.  The resized image quality in chrome stops looking quite as good.  

Normally images in chrome (after being resized) first look not quite perfect, but then a second later chrome loads in a better version of the image.  This CSS property appears to stop this.  

It looks "good enough" for me, and much closer to IE and Firefox...and therefore the panning now works very smoothly.

Comment: Ok if the lack of antialising bothers you, switch -webkit-backface-visibility to hidden on drag and turn it on again on release.

Comment: Very cool.  Is the antialiasing with chrome documented anywhere?  Or is it documented why it goes away with backface-visibility?  Overall, your suggestion is exactly what I needed, I am just curious how you even found that out.